# Problem when saving a png to jpg in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, png

I'm running this piece of code and getting a wrong result:

```
        #saving image into a white bg
        img = cv2.imread(dir_img + id, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
        print(img.shape)
        cv2.imwrite(dir_img + id, img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
```

[image]

The original file is a png with a transparent background. I don't know why but it's saving with this grey pattern behind the bottle neck.

Original File:
[image]

Comment: Can you share original file?

Comment: probably because your image has that gray pattern behind, but it's "hidden" by the alpha channel

Comment: @Alderven Original File uploaded

Comment: @Miki how do I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, simply removing the alpha channel does not remove the background in this case because the BGR channel has the artifact you are trying to remove, as is shown below when you only plot the B, G or R channel.

[image: B channel]

And your alpha channel looks like this

[image: alpha channel]

To achieve what you need, you'll need to apply some matrix math to get your result. I've attached the code here

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_path = r"path/to/image"

#saving image into a white bg
img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
b,g,r, a = cv2.split(img)
print(img.shape)

new_img  = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
not_a = cv2.bitwise_not(a)
not_a = cv2.cvtColor(not_a, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
plt.imshow(not_a)
plt.show()
new_img = cv2.bitwise_and(new_img,new_img,mask = a)
new_img = cv2.add(new_img, not_a)

cv2.imwrite(output_dir, new_img)
plt.imshow(new_img)
print(new_img.shape)
plt.show()
```

The result being an image with dimensions `(1200, 1200, 3)`

[image]